# Cost in Scala of iteratively manipulating functions rather than simpler types

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold, higher-order-functions

Having spent some time exploring Haskell, I've become used to building and manipulating chains of functions - and to assessing how this will perform in non-strict evaluation.  I realise I do not understand well how that style performs in Scala.

To take a simple example, imagine that the Scala **List** had no append method.  You could concatenate two lists of integers like this:

```
  xs.reverse.foldLeft(ys)(_.::(_))
```

(Yes, I know Scala recently changed **foldRight** so that it just does **reverse.foldLeft**.  *sigh*)

An alternative is to build up a function chain like this:

```
  xs.foldLeft(identity[List[Int]] _)((f, a) => f compose (a :: _)) (ys)
```

In non-strict Haskell, the second approach is often better because it is *"productive"* and the entire chain will not necessarily be evaluated (I know, in Haskell you would just use a right fold for this).  But in Scala, these two approaches will perform similarly.  Both are **O(n)**.  Both are effectively creating a reversed collection on the heap and then iteratively consing that onto **ys** (you can think of the second style as creating a linked list of functions).

I have a general inclination towards the second style, but my question is: are there hidden gotchas (performance penalties I had not considered, significantly higher heap usage, that kind of thing) in this approach?  In Scala, what factors should I keep in mind (other than code readability) when choosing between manipulating data or functions?

Comment: I see somebody has flagged this as too broad.  I object.  I have asked if there are any specific technical problems in Scala's implementation of higher order functions which make their use more dangerous than is immediately apparent.  I have provided two alternative ways of doing exactly the same thing, so that if there are problems with the second approach, these can be contrasted.  So this is quite a specific, technical question.  If it seems too broad to the flagger, I suggest this is because they do not understand the question.

Comment: As soon as you start asking about "hidden gotchas" with a short list ending with "that kind of things" and "factors I should keep in mind" your question becomes too broad. But hey, I may be wrong and you'll get a neat answer.

Comment: I've given very specific context and a concrete implementation.  Dangers are likely to be few, if any, and well known to people more experienced in Scala than I.   Would it make you happier if it said "Are there any specific, well-known penalties to using higher-order-functions in the way I have demonstrated?"  Because that is the question.  Elsewhere on an SE site I've been busy telling somebody why case classes are a bad fit to his problem.  He showed his code, asking "Are case classes bad for this?".  He didn't know enough about them to ask more.  His question is not too broad. Nor is this.

Comment: Why don't you just do benchmarks and compare CPU time and heap consumption for the two solutions? In general though, Scalac+Hotspot is much worse at performing optimization of functional code (especially lazy) than GHC is, but typically very good at optimizing code working on data. And List is typically not the best data structure to use if you care about performance.

Comment: *Sigh* I do know what lists are good for and what they are bad at.   I *have* benchmarked different strategies.  In the example above, **reverse.foldLeft** is faster for small and simple datasets but you can see significant gains with the higher order function approach in more complex cases, because less wasteful duplication occurs.  But I am no expert on Scala's internal implementation and benchmarking will not always tell me *why* there is a problem, so would be interested to hear from people with that knowledge and experience.

Comment: If there are problems which often confound the HoF approach *because* of Scala's internal implementation, that will be known to some and it seems bizarre that you feel it odd of me to ask here.  I could go chat to Runar Bjarnason somewhere else (although he is on here sometimes) but since there are quite a few Scala wizards on here, I might get an answer that other people would benefit from, like the person who favourited this question.  I thought that might be what the site was for, @JesperNordenberg.  Look at my profile: I am not a time waster on this site.

Comment: Whoa, take it easy. I never criticized you for asking the question (or your competence on the topic), I just gave some general tips about optimization not knowing your level of knowledge about Hotspot/JVM (as scalac in general does very little in the form of optimizations (this might change in Scala 2.12 though)). In fact I would be very interested in reading a reply since it's a quite complex topic to reason about.

Comment: Thanks.  In Haskell there certainly are pitfalls in HoF implementations, which *can* be summarised clearly but are not in the standard documentation nor in the tutorials like Learn You a Haskell.  If somebody asked this question here with a Haskell tag, I would be able to give a reasonable answer (although, again, there are much more knowledgeable people on this site) to what I would see as a reasonable question.